# Center text div in slider

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to center a text div in a custom slider.

For some reason the CSS won't work. The website is on my test server at http://bit.ly/ZgawU6

I want to center the group of text 'Environmental Concern' in the top slider. Similar to this website www.sevenly.org

It works when I change the div to position:relative, instead of position:absolute; however I can only change it with Chrome inspector. When I add it to the CSS file it doesn't work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this code isn't working?

```
.custom-slider-caption, .custom-slider-title {
line-height: 1.3;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}
```

The div in question:

```
<div class="custom-slider-title" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1;"><div style="position: absolute; left:”0″px; top:140px; right:”0″px; bottom:px; font-size: 43px; color:#fff; text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px #497ca0; ">Environmental Concern</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't works on an absolute position because absolute positioned elements aren't 100% width. You can set the witdh to 100%, or, a bit **cleaner solution** would be to set the `right` value to zero. So you will have `left` and `right` positions to zero and width will be automatically be 100%.

```
div {
  positon: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

You even don't need to specify `px` if value is qual to zero, because any dimension set to zero in %, em, px or whatever will all have the same size. **Zero is zero**.

Comment: Legend, thanks for the detailed and thorough explanation! It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
.custom-slider-caption, .custom-slider-title {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this if you want the div to be centred

```
#div
{
 width:600px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}

// NOTE: THE WIDTH CAN BE CHANGED //

#div p
{
 width:300px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of pzin is correct. Use this selector:

```
.custom-slider-title > div {
    ...
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
```

}